# SignalR - how to detect disconnected clients

Tags: asp.net, signalr

How to detect which clients was disconnected? I'm using Hub and saw the chat example where the `IDisconnect` interface was implemented. De `Disconnect()` function is called when a page is refreshed or closed, for example. It's working ok, but how to detect which one was disconnected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a Client id property on the Hub (Context.ClientId) that you can use to figure out which client disconnected.